Adapt existing script for converting csv to html table to include <tfoot>
I've used the code below for several years to convert selected data in a large csv file into an html table. It selects a specific range of rows and columns to present.
Is it possible to add a command to wrap the last four selected rows in a tfoot tag? So in this example, rows 167-170. Similar to row 147 being wrapper in a thead.
<?php
        $row = 1;
        
        if(($handle = fopen("CSV/thesfpsquads23.csv", "r")) !== false) {
        
            $table1 = '<table id="exampleaugnov" class="sfpsquad augnov">';
        
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        
                $table1Add = false;
                if($row >=147 && $row <= 170)
                    $table1Add = true;
        
                $num = count($data);
        
                if($row == 147) {
        
                    $table1 .= '<thead><tr>';
        
                    for($c = 0; $c <= 21; $c++) {
                        $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "0" : $data[$c];
        
                        $table1 .= '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
                    }
        
                    $table1 .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
        
                } else {
        
                    if($table1Add) $table1 .= '<tr>';
        
                    for($c = 0; $c <= 21; $c++) {
                        $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "0" : $data[$c];
        
                        if($table1Add) $table1 .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
                    }
        
                    if($table1Add) $table1 .= '</tr>';
        
                }
        
                $row++;
        
            }
        
            $table1 .= '</tbody></table>';
            fclose($handle);
        
            echo $table1;
        }
        ?>


What's a "selected" row? Do you mean rows 167-170?

Well, this code can be improved, try using an AI, but let's just get it working, hopefully.
Row 140 - inside <thead>
Row 167-170 inside <tfoot>
in between in <tbody>
and other rows discarded.
$row = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("CSV/thesfpsquads23.csv", "r")) !== false) {
    $table1 = '<table id="exampleaugnov" class="sfpsquad augnov">';
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $row++;
        if ($row < 147 || $row > 170) {
            continue;
        }
        $num = count($data);
        if ($row == 147) {
            $table1 .= '<thead><tr>';
            for ($c = 0; $c <= 21; $c++) {
                $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "0" : $data[$c];
                $table1 .= '<th>' . $value . '</th>';
            }
            $table1 .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
        } else {
            if ($row == 167) {
                $table1 .= '</tbody><tfoot>';
            }

            $table1 .= '<tr>';
            for ($c = 0; $c <= 21; $c++) {
                $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "0" : $data[$c];
                $table1 .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
            }
            $table1 .= '</tr>';

            if ($row == 170) {
                $table1 .= '</tfoot>';
            }
        }
    }
    $table1 .= '</table>';
    fclose($handle);
    echo $table1;
}


Thank you so much. Perfect, works exactly how I wanted.
